# Sorting by the first element in a nested type array

Tags: sorting, nested, elasticsearch

According to this link [describing the addition of sorting by nested fields to ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2662):

> Either the highest (max) or lowest (min) inner object is picked for during sorting depending on the sort_mode being used.

Is there any way, instead of having it use the highest or lowest value, it uses the *first* value of the array? So for example, if the record looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "Blah blah blah",
    "authors": [
        {
            "last": "Reiter",
            "first": "Jordan",
        },
        {
            "last": "Jim",
            "first": "Lee",
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to sort by `authors.last, authors.first` for the given record it would use `Reiter, Jordan` for sorting?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not.

I'd suggest storing the author you want to sort by in the parent document, i.e.

```
title: "Blah blah"
sortByAuthor: "Jordan Reiter"
authors: [
    ...
]
```

You can possibly get away with your current structure using a script, but you'll be loading a lot more into memory than necessary then.